# Is it better to do evaluation of bool once with more code or multiple times with less code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it better to evaluate `bool` once but have more code like this

```
 if (klient.Podmioty.PodmiotRodzaj == "Osoba") {
     textImie.Enabled = true;
     textNazwisko.Enabled = true;
     textNazwa.Enabled = false;
 } else {
     textImie.Enabled = false;
     textNazwisko.Enabled = false;
     textNazwa.Enabled = true;
 }
```

comparing to this

```
      textImie.Enabled = klient.Podmioty.PodmiotRodzaj == "Osoba";
      textNazwisko.Enabled = klient.Podmioty.PodmiotRodzaj == "Osoba";
      textNazwa.Enabled = klient.Podmioty.PodmiotRodzaj != "Osoba";
```

It's a generic question and maybe this little example is micro optimization but I would like to know whether reusing same bool over and over is not considered bad code.

Probably useful note is that `klient.Podmioty.PodmiotRodzaj` is actually variable from SQL brought by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Evaluate once and use the results:

```
var conditionValue = (klient.Podmioty.PodmiotRodzaj == "Osoba");

textImie.Enabled = conditionValue;
textNazwisko.Enabled = conditionValue;
textNazwa.Enabled = !conditionValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I had blackout :)

Answer (score 4):

The first option, less calculation time and no replica of code...

or, option C:

```
bool value = klient.Podmioty.PodmiotRodzaj == "Osoba";
textImie.Enabled = value;
textNazwisko.Enabled = value;
textNazwa.Enabled = !value;
```

but definitely not your option B.

Answer (score 0):

The first is the common answer, and the second is hard to read.  However, since you're only setting bools to the same as the condition, there's a third option:

```
bool t = (klient.podmioty.PodmiotRodzaj == "Osaba");
TextImed.Enabled = t;
TextNazwisko.Enabled = t;
TextNazwa.Enabled = !t;
```

(On phone, so I prob got the variable names wrong)  This is debatibly slightly less clear than the first option, but brief (and avoids code forks).